# Java 8 thenApply() and thenAccept()

Tags: concurrency, java-8

I'm creating a demonstration example for chaining `CompleteableFuture` operations and I think I'm close but there's something I'm missing. Everything compiles except for the final "Build cakes in parallel" clause in `main()`:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.time.*;

// Use decorator pattern to build up the cake:

interface Cake_ {
  String describe();
}

class Cake implements Cake_ {
  private int id;
  public Cake(int id) { this.id = id; }
  @Override
  public String describe() {
    return "Cake " + id;
  }
}

abstract class Decorator implements Cake_ {
  protected Cake_ cake;
  public Decorator(Cake_ cake) {
    this.cake = cake;
  }
  @Override
  public String describe() {
    return cake.describe();
  }
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return describe();
  }
}

class Frosted extends Decorator {
  public Frosted(Cake_ cake) {
    super(cake);
  }
  @Override
  public String describe() {
    return cake.describe() + " Frosted";
  }
}

class Decorated extends Decorator {
  public Decorated(Cake_ cake) {
    super(cake);
  }
  @Override
  public String describe() {
    return cake.describe() + " Decorated";
  }
}

// For the cake-building assembly line:

class CreateCakes implements Supplier<Cake> {
  private int id;
  public CreateCakes(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
  @Override
  public Cake get() {
    return new Cake(id);
  }
}

class FrostCakes implements Function<Cake, Frosted> {
  @Override
  public Frosted apply(Cake cake) {
    return new Frosted(cake);
  }
}

class DecorateCakes implements Consumer<Frosted> {
  public Decorated result;
  @Override
  public void accept(Frosted fc) {
    result = new Decorated(fc);
  }
}

public class Test {
  public static int NUM_OF_CAKES = 20;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Change from the default number of threads:
    System.setProperty(
      "java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool" +
      ".common.parallelism", "" + NUM_OF_CAKES);

    // Test/demonstrate the decorator pattern:
    List<Cake_> decorated =
      IntStream.range(0, NUM_OF_CAKES)
        .mapToObj(Cake::new)
        .map(Frosted::new)
        .map(Decorated::new)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    decorated.forEach(System.out::println);

    // Build cakes in parallel:
    List<CompletableFuture<?>> futures =
      IntStream.range(0, NUM_OF_CAKES)
        .mapToObj(id -> new CreateCakes(id))
        .map(CompletableFuture::supplyAsync)
        .thenApply(new FrostCakes())
        .thenAccept(new DecorateCakes())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    futures.forEach(CompletableFuture::join);
  }
}
```

I realize I'm missing some fundamental understanding in the definition of the `futures` list, but I've included it to show what I'm *trying* to accomplish here: a cake factory with portions of the cake-creation process running in parallel.

Comment: When asking about a compilation error, post the compilation error.

Comment: You're calling thenApply() on a Stream. Stream doesn't have any thenApply() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick answer to your question will be that the `thenApply` line doesn't compile because the result from the line above (`map(CompletableFuture::supplyAsync)`) returns `Stream<CompletableFuture<Cake>>` and not `CompletableFuture<Cake>`.
You'll need to do something like `map(cakeFuture -> cakeFuture.thenApply(new FrostCakes()))`.

But I think there's a more important point that needs to be made.

If your examples are meant for educational purposes, I'd recommend investing another day or two in preparation, and more specifically in reading about the fundamentals of stream operations and `CompletableFuture`.

This way you'll feel much more confident when you get to present your material, but more importantly, you won't be presenting less than perfect code examples that can potentially harm your colleagues/students notion about how can streams and `CompletableFuture`s (and even decorators) be used.

I'll point out some of the things that I think need to be redone in your examples.

1. Manually setting the parallelism level of the common `ForkJoinPool` is not always a good idea. By default, it uses the number of processors, as returned by `Runtime.availableProcessors()` which is a pretty good default. You need to have a pretty good reason to change it to something more than that, because in most cases you'll just be introducing unnecessary overhead from scheduling and maintenance of redundant threads. And to change it to the number of tasks you're planning to fire is almost always a bad idea (explanation omitted).
2. Your stream examples perform a couple of stream operations, then terminate with a collection, and then a stream operation is performed on the collected list. They can be rewritten without the collection to list, by directly applying the `forEach` on the stream returned by the last mapping, and arguably this will be a better demonstration of the fluent programming model using Java 8 streams.
3. Your examples also don't perform their operations in parallel. You can fix that easily by adding `.parallel()` after `IntStream.range()`, but unless you remove the redundant collection to list from above, you won't be able to see that you've done something in parallel just by printing the list contents with `forEach`.
4. Your classes implementing the `java.util.function` interfaces are not very idiomatic. I would argue that they should be replaced with the corresponding lambda expressions even though in your case this could result in a mouthful lambda in lambda, unless your second example is slightly rewritten.
5. `CompletableFuture.thenAccept` returns a `CompletableFuture<Void>`, so in this stage of your stream processing you lose the references to the created, frosted and decorated cakes. This can be OK if you don't care about them, or if you log something about them in the decoration logic, but your example can easily mislead people that the finally collected list of `CompletableFuture`s can be used to reach to the cakes (after all, who doesn't want to have his cake and eat it too).

So your first example can look something like

```
IntStream.range(0, NUM_OF_CAKES)
        .parallel()
        .mapToObj(Cake::new)
        .map(Frosted::new)
        .map(Decorated::new)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Notice how the cake IDs are not ordered because of the parallel execution.